# SASS/SCSS using @extend across individual files (responsive design)

Tags: responsive-design, sass

I'm using a "mobile first" approach on my site, and I'm utilizing SCSS.

I have 3 SCSS stylesheets:

- `base.scss` (served to all)
- `medium.scss` (>= 768px window)
- `large.scss` (>= 1024px window)

They are served like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/medium.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 767px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/large.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1023px)" />
```

In other words, `large.scss` has no knowledge of the css in `base.scss`, yet I need to extend a class that resides in `base.css`, when in `large.scss`.

How can I do this?

I tried separating the elements I need to extend, such as the buttons, into a separate stylesheet, and then use `@import 'buttons.scss';` in `medium.scss`, but then all the css in `buttons.scss` will be rendered in that sheet as well.

Are there any way to make expose classes in base.scss to the SASS "rendering engine" when compiling the css so that they can be used in medium.scss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar issue recently. My solution: mixins.

_mixins.scss

```
@mixin someSpacing($base: 5px;){
    padding: $base;
    margin: $base;
}
```

Remember to use underscore as prefix, sass wont compile those files. So now you can simply import _mixins.scss to your files. Additionally you can extend your mixin with parameters to give you more flexibility.

e.g.
base.scss

```
    @import '_mixins.scss';

    .classA {
        @include someSpacing(3px);
    }
```

large.scss

```
    @import '_mixins.scss';

    .anotherClass {
        @include someSpacing(10px);
    }
```

more details in sass reference:
http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins

Comment: This answer is now outdated. SASS/SCSS now supports cross-file `@extend` when using `@import` on that file.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but in this case those scss files are independent from each other - so those files doesn't know about each others classes.

Comment: @GeReV I think @ import copies all the declarations from one file and sticks them in another. Maybe that's not desireable when you just want to inherit one declaration?

Answer (score 2):

I needed this as well once. I asked Chris Eppstein today and he said:

> extend is per output file

So yeah. @include is your only hope.

Comment: IMHO that should be fixed asap

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach to your task is to store all the extendable selectors in partials and import those partials into your output files.

**project/partials/_extendables.sass**

```
.foo
  color: red

%bar
  width: 50px
```

**project/base.sass**

```
@import partials/extendables

.baz
  @extend .foo
```

**project/medium.sass**

```
@import partials/extendables

.quux
  @extend %bar
```

Also, the approach you're using for organizing the responsiveness i heavily outdated. Unless you're forced to support some old rusty version of IE, you should use the modern approach:

- A single output file.
- Code organized into many small partials, grouped by page components (menu, news list, news item, etc) and by function (sticky footer technique, typography), rather than grouping it by media queries or by where elements appear on the page (e. g. all header code, all sidebar code).
- Media queries should be applied granularly, in-place, using the Sass media query bubbling feature:

  **project/partials/components/_menu.sass**

  ```
  .menu

     @media (max-width: 600px)
       // Mobile styles for menu container

     @media (min-width: 601px)
       // Desktop styles for menu container


  .menu-item

     @media (max-width: 600px)
       // Mobile styles for menu items

     @media (min-width: 601px)
       // Desktop styles for menu items
  ```